# Parsing NSString to NSDate using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have such string: "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 1:59 pm EEST"
i am trying to set these parsing rules:

```
[formatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a z"];
```

but this returns `nil` when i perform:

```
[formatter dateFromString: @"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 1:59 pm EEST"];
```

What's the right regular expression for such format?

Comment: Just to tip, will not fix your issue, you should set the local of the dateformatter to english. Because if your iOS device is net set to english your dateformatting will fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nsdateformatter + Timezone issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763420/nsdateformatter-timezone-issue)

Comment: Yeah, it may be a locale problem.  Since you are using English terms you should use an English/US locale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz"];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:@"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 1:59 PM EEST"];
    NSLog(@"date: %@",date);

O/P:-date: 2013-10-22 10:59:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

`hh` is a padded hour ("01" in your case) but your string doesn't have padded hours (just "1" ) so it should be just `h` instead.

You can see a practical examples of the different formatting components below (output from [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/d-ronnqvist/6600444)). The date being formatted is `1987-08-27 15:24:03`

```
format  result
--------------
    yy  87
  yyyy  1987
     M  8
    MM  08
   MMM  Aug
  MMMM  August
    dd  27
    HH  15
    hh  03    // <--.
     h  3     // <--'--- note the difference
     a  PM
    mm  24
     m  24
    ss  03
     s  3
```