# Have troubles with NSDateFormatter while parsing

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

Here is the date sample: Wed, 13 May 2015 16:10:00 CEST

My formatter aint working

```
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss vvvv"
```

What should i change?

UPD: full code

```
NSString* formattedDayWithString(NSString* date){
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *localeId = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier
                                         value:[locale localeIdentifier]];

SLog(@"%@ date:%@", localeId, date);
[inputFormatter setLocale: locale];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss vvvv"];
NSDate *formattedDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString: date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"d'.' MMMM yyyy"];

NSString* dateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate]];
return dateStr;
```

}

Comment: Show actual code in your question. And indicate what locale you are in.

Comment: Study up on [time zone names](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Using_Time_Zone_Names) (and have fun!)

Comment: What locale are you in? BTW - it's pointless to set the formatter's locale to the current locale since that is the default.

Comment: And what happens when you run the code? What do you get for each variable?

Comment: English (U.S.) , is it important?

Comment: Formatted date is nil

Comment: Yes, the locale is important because the date string is in English. If your locale was for some other language, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"CEST" is a "short specific non-location format" and the corresponding
date field symbol is "z", not "v":

```
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
```

In addition, you might have to set the date formatter locale explicitly to "en_GB"
as explained in [Nsdateformatter + Timezone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763420/nsdateformatter-timezone-issue).

Comment: @Leonid: It worked for me. Have you set the locale to en_GB as well?