# need to get central time in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimezone

I have app where i need to get the current time (CST). I'm trying to use the following code but the NDate is the same as GMT:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"Time is %@", [date description]);

    [NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];
    NSDate* nDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"Central time is%@", [nDate description])
```

Comment: An NSDate is *supposed* to be GMT.  If it isn't you screwed up somewhere.

Comment: NSLog will print to your console, therefore it will use your system (Mac) timezone.

Comment: @HotLicks, `NSDate` is not "supposed to be GMT". It's not supposed to be in any time zone. Time zones as a concept are completely orthogonal to what `NSDate` represents. Even `-[NSDate description]` is not "supposed to be GMT". It's unspecified, which is part of what makes that method unsuitable for anything other than debugging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected value from NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate)

Comment: @KenThomases - In theory.  In practice the value inside an NSDate is GMT/UTC, and the `description` representation is always with zero timezone offset.  There is, I suspect, a timezone offset field in the object, but it's been hard-wired to zero for about 5 years now.

Comment: First, it doesn't matter what the value inside an `NSDate` is. But you're wrong about that, anyway. The value is simply a number of seconds since a particular reference date. Even if that reference date is especially round when represented in GMT, that doesn't make the time indicated by adding an interval to it have a time zone. Times don't have a time zone except when represented as strings or components relative to a calendar. It just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the fact that the time has not timezone itself, but you have to add a calendar to set it in relation to a time zone as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294289/unexpected-value-from-nsdate/17296378#17296378), you should not use a tz abbreviation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763420/nsdateformatter-timezone-issue).

Answer (score 0):

> but the NSDate is the same as GMT

That's right, and if you look at the printout, it *says* that it is showing you GMT. Therefore, it is giving you the *right answer* — the date-time, right now, in terms of GMT. The current time CST *is* the GMT date-time it is showing you.

That is what `description` does. If that isn't what you wanted, why did you use `description`?

Answer (score 0):

An `NSDate` doesn't have a time zone. It's a moment in time. A moment exists across all time zones. The string it gives from `-description` has to pick a time zone in order to represent the moment, because that's the way we write dates and times, but which it picks is arbitrary. The time zone used for the description in **no way** represents any fundamental fact about the nature of the `NSDate` object.

If you want to format a date into a string, don't use `-description` because it's not well-defined. (For example, which time zone it uses has changed before with the version of OS X and could change again.) Use an `NSDateFormatter`. You can configure an `NSDateFormatter` with a time zone by setting its `timeZone` property.

If you want to get information about the date, like month, day, hour, minute, etc., use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`.